# How can I know what server a reply / match is played on in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I know programming and am aware of the Dota 2 API. However, after searching about I couldn't find out whether the information about the region / server of the match / replay is stored somewhere.

This is necessary as I plan to analyze replays based on which regions they are from.

Comment: This appears to be possible, as [Dotabuff displays the region](http://www.dotabuff.com/matches/1034311388), but I'm not sure how...

Comment: Check out [skadistats/smoke](https://github.com/skadistats/smoke), a Python interface into Dota2 replay files. If you're planning on doing analysis of replays it would be a very useful tool.

Comment: Do you know how this replay parser compares with one by cyborgmatt ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to know the Server if you know the replay id of the game. If you have obtained the replay id match, you can paste it here [http://www.dotabuff.com/](http://www.dotabuff.com). After that, the overview of the match will be reflected and the server is found on the top part fourth column.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do that programmatically though. Do you have any idea how dotabuff does that?

Comment: Just as I thought. Currently, I haven't tried the dota2 api so I'm really not aware of their methods. I also tried searching if dotabuff has their own api that might help (or any info about servers), but unfortunately. they said that they are just using the dota2 api and did not explain it further. This is the farthest I can go. Good luck to you sir.